# Cannot capture notes into separate org file when entering reference into Bibtex with ivy

Tags: org-capture, ivy, bibtex

I am using emacs 27.1-4.1 with Spacemacs v.o.200.13 Ivy and vims. I am relatively new to emacs and am expanding into bibtex with ivy-bibtex. in my .spacemacs file is:

(autoload 'ivy-bibtex "ivy-bibtex" "" t)

(setq ivy-re-builders-alist

```
  '((ivy-bibtex . ivy--regex-ignore-order)
    (t . ivy--regex-plus)))
```

(setq bibtex-completion-bibliography '("/home/rherbert/Documents/Library/Bib_Files/FN_Rights.bib")

```
  bibtex-completion-library-path '("/home/rherbert/Documents/Library/Bib_PDFs/")
  bibtex-completion-notes-path "/home/rherbert/Documents/Library/Bib_Files/FN_Quotes.org")
```

(setq bibtex-completion-additional-search-fields '(keywords))

(setq bibtex-completion-format-citation-functions

```
  '((org-mode      . bibtex-completion-format-citation-org-title-link-to-PDF)
    (latex-mode    . bibtex-completion-format-citation-cite)
    (markdown-mode . bibtex-completion-format-citation-pandoc-citeproc)
    (default       . bibtex-completion-format-citation-default)))
```

(setq bibtex-completion-pdf-symbol "⌘")

(setq bibtex-completion-notes-symbol "✎")

I have no problem entering references in the bib file. After filing in the bibtex template I C-c to cleanit up and then :w to save. There is no problem searching the bib file with ivy-bibtex. However, bibtex does not capture a note and send it into the .org file set to receive it.

Any suggestions for why the capture is not working?

[note that the symbol for notes does not work either, but that is a minor problem]

Comment: My OS is Opensuse Tumbleweed.

Comment: So, I scrubbed a laptop and did a fresh install of emacs and spacemacs (emacs 27.1-4.1 with Spacemacs v.o.200.13 Ivy) onto Opensuse Tumbleweed using helm instead. I also removed all code for ivy-bibtex from my dotspacemacs/user/conifg. It still does not capture. Bibtex is in dotspacemacs-configuration-layers. It is likely I am doing some very basic function wrong.